# match part of text based on another column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, match

I have this dataset;

```
text                                    num

test one 3.5 and 60 test tow            3.5/60
test one 3/4 test tow                     3/4
test one 5.0 test 10 tow                  5.0
```

I need to remove the number from text column if it match in num
so I have did this:

```
df['text']=[re.sub('{}'.format(number), '', the_text) for the_text, number in zip(df['text'], df['num'])]
```

the result become like

```
text                                    num

test one 3.5 and 60 test tow            3.5/60
test one test tow                         3/4
test one test 10 tow                      5.0
```

as you can see the matched number was removed except the first row because it is not an exact match.
so I want to use contains function match or anything similar to match part of a text.

I expect the first row will become

> test one and test tow

I have did this but get error:

```
[re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(word), "", the_text) for the_text, word in zip(df['text'], word='/'.join([r'{}'.format(words) for words in df['num']]) )]

TypeError: zip() takes no keyword arguments
```

any help?

Comment: If you say you got an error, always post the error message.

Comment: Instead of `'{}'.format(number)`, try `r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)(?:{})(?!\.?\d)'.format('|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in number.split('/')]))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not work

Comment: @JoelFan I did thank you

Comment: Is your example data frame `df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['test one 3.5 and 60 test tow','test one 3/4 test tow', 'test one 5.0 test tow'], 'num': ['3.5/60', '3/4', '5.0']})`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes also,I have did some changes on the question to the sample data to make it more clear why I do not use a list.

Comment: Ok, try `df['text'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)(?:{}|{})(?!\.?\d)'.format(re.escape(x['num']), '|'.join([re.escape(l) for l in x['num'].split('/')])), '', x['text']), axis=1)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it worked thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
df['text'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)(?:{}|{})(?!\.?\d)'.format(re.escape(x['num']), '|'.join([re.escape(l) for l in x['num'].split('/')])), '', x['text']), axis=1)
```

Thanks to `df.apply` and `axis=1`, we iterate over all rows.

The regex is made dynamically based on the value in the `num` column and is applied to `text` column.

`r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)(?:{}|{})(?!\.?\d)'.format(re.escape(x['num']), '|'.join([re.escape(l) for l in x['num'].split('/')]))` creates a regex like

```
(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)(?:3/4|3|4)(?!\.?\d)
```

that matches both full value in the `num` column and the numbers in between `/` separately.

The `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)` are a lookbehind sequence that fail the match if there is a digit or a digit + dot immediately to the left of the current position, and `(?!\.?\d)` fails the match if there is a digit or a dot + digit immediately to the right of the current position effectively disallowing number matches in longer numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import re

txt='''\
text                                    num

test one 3.5 and 60 test tow            3.5/60
test one 3/4 test tow                     3/4
test one 5.0 test tow                     5.0'''

for line in txt.splitlines():
    m=re.search(r'^(.*?[ \t]{2,}(?=\d))([0-9.\/]+)$', line)
    if m:
        a,_,b=m.group(2).partition('/')
        if re.search(fr'\b{m.group(2)}\b', m.group(1)):
            l=len(m.group(1))
            s=re.sub(fr'[ ]?\b{m.group(2)}\b', '', m.group(1))
            line=s+' '*(l-len(s))+m.group(2)
        elif re.search(fr'{a}[^/]+{b}', m.group(1)):
            l=len(m.group(1))
            s=re.sub(fr'[ ]?\b{a}\b','',m.group(1))
            s=re.sub(fr'[ ]?\b{b}\b','',s)
            line=s+' '*(l-len(s))+m.group(2)
                
    print(line)
```

Prints:

```
text                                    num

test one and test tow                   3.5/60
test one test tow                         3/4
test one test tow                         5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of the numbers and also add the `/`

```
nums = '|'.join(df['num'].tolist()).replace('/', '|') + '|/'
nums
'3.5|60|3|4|5.0|/'
```

Then str replace

```
df['text'].str.replace(nums, '')

0    test one  and  test tow
1         test one  test tow
2         test one  test tow
```

Comment: Note that `.` is a special regex metacharacter, `5.0` will match `5 0`, `5+0` and many more. You need to escape it. Besides, without any boundaries, you will risk replacing `3` in `43`.

Comment: I want to pass the num column so that each row will match the same row on text column

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so if there is any other number on the text that will not remove if not match